# Buffered input causes strange variable output

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm trying to load a variable in assembly from user input. The variable appears to be stored correctly, but the output behaves strangely. When printing 3 variables that I filled with buffered input they are all printed on the same place.

For example if I input these variables:

```
strA = 'aaaaa'
strB = 'bbb'
strC = 'c'
```

I get this output:

```
cbbaa
```

Instead of this output:

```
aaaaabbbc
```

I have defined these variables in data segment:

```
strA_prompt 'Enter string A: $'
strA_buffer_args db 32, 0
strA db 32 DUP('$')
strB_prompt 'Enter string B: $'
strB_buffer_args db 32, 0
strB db 32 DUP('$')
strC_prompt 'Enter string C: $'
strC_buffer_args db 32, 0
strC db 32 DUP('$')
```

This is the relevant code segment:

```
; READ INPUT

mov dx, offset strA_prompt
mov ah, 9
int 21h
mov dx, offset strA_buffer_args
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10
int 21h

mov dx, offset strB_prompt
mov ah, 9
int 21h
mov dx, offset strB_buffer_args
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10
int 21h

mov dx, offset strC_prompt
mov ah, 9
int 21h
mov dx, offset strC_buffer_args
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10
int 21h

; PRINT VARIABLES

mov ah, 9
mov dx, offset strA
int 21h
mov dx, offset strB
int 21h
mov dx, offset strC
int 21h
```

What am I doing incorrectly? How do I make them print next to each other as they normally should?

Comment: Sounds like you have the `\r` (carriage return) at the end of the strings. Cut that off.

Comment: E.g. `movzx bx, byte ptr [strA_buffer_args+1]; mov byte ptr [strA+bx], '$'` or similar (do it for all the strings).

Comment: @Jester: `movzx` is 386+

Comment: So it is. Nobody said it's 8086. Also I said "or similar".

Answer (score 1):

When calling buffered input, used string gets carriage return (ASCII 13) at the end. I just had to replace it with '$'.